Github Actions Fails To Load From Cache For Python Virtual Environment
I have the following CI/CD pipeline for one of my ml projects and with this, I would like to cache my venv, so that successive pipeline runs faster.
name: CI/CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        id: setup_python
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Cache venv directory
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: ./.boston_house_price_prediction_venv
          #fail-on-cache-miss: true
          key: venv-${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/_requirements_1.txt') }}

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m venv .boston_house_price_prediction_venv
          source .boston_house_price_prediction_venv/bin/activate
          echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
          echo "******************** Created Python Virtual Environment ********************"
          python -m pip install -r requirements_1.txt
          echo "******************** Successfully installed dependencies ********************"

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          # Replace this line with the command to run your tests
          pytest --cov=src src/tests/boston_housing_price_prediction/test_*.py

However, when this is run in GitHub Actions pipeline, I see the following:
0s
Run actions/cache@v4
  with:
    path: ./.boston_house_price_prediction_venv
    key: venv-Linux-
    enableCrossOsArchive: false
    fail-on-cache-miss: false
    lookup-only: false
    save-always: false
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib
Cache not found for input keys: venv-Linux-

And this is what I see for installing dependencies:
Run python -m venv .boston_house_price_prediction_venv
  python -m venv .boston_house_price_prediction_venv
  source .boston_house_price_prediction_venv/bin/activate
  echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
  echo "******************** Created Python Virtual Environment ********************"
  python -m pip install -r requirements_1.txt
  echo "******************** Successfully installed dependencies ********************"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib/pkgconfig
    Python_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    Python2_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    Python3_ROOT_DIR: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.9/x64/lib
/home/runner/work/nn-playground/nn-playground/.boston_house_price_prediction_venv
******************** Created Python Virtual Environment ********************

Looking at where tge venv is created, I see that the name of the project is appearing twice

"/home/runner/work/nn-playground/nn-playground/"

But I can't see why this is the case? So, how can I ensure that my cache is loaded?

I had a look into the pipeline run and I can see that my tests are failing and as a result of that the "Post Cache vent directory" step is not run, hence the cache is not created. I can fix this by not running my unit tests initially as I need some time to fix them. Is this the approach? Can I still force the cache creation?
